# Quasar exportFile utf-8 encoding

Tags: vue.js, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, quasar-framework

I am using [Quasar freamwork](https://quasar.dev/) and Perisan words in my site. I used [Export-data util](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#exporting-data) for exporting csv file from data tables.

This is js codes that export data :

```
function wrapCsvValue(val, formatFn) {
  let formatted = formatFn !== void 0
    ? formatFn(val)
    : val
  formatted = formatted === void 0 || formatted === null
    ? ''
    : String(formatted)
  formatted = formatted.split('"').join('""')
  return `"${formatted}"`
}


exportTable() {
  const content = [this.columns.map(col => wrapCsvValue(col.label))].concat(
    this.rows.map(row => this.columns.map(col => wrapCsvValue(
      typeof col.field === 'function'
        ? col.field(row)
        : row[col.field === void 0 ? col.name : col.field],
      col.format
    )).join(','))
  ).join('\r\n')

  const status = exportFile(
    'table-export.csv',
    content,
    'text/csv'
  )
}
```

When I export table, this returns unreadable data when I open it in excel. but when I use it on online excel viewers It is okay. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

```
const status = exportFile(
'table-export.csv',
"ufeff"+content,
'text/csv')
```

Comment: He forgot to use \            current answer is : 
"\ufeff"+content,

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
    const status = exportFile(
            `${t('device.deviceList.device_Name')}-${fileName}.csv`,
            content,
            {
              encoding: "utf-8",
              mimeType: "text/csv",
              byteOrderMark: "\uFEFF",
            }
          )
```

[github.com](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/12934)

[jianshu.com](https://www.jianshu.com/p/3c58f474d7d6)

[blog.51cto.com](https://blog.51cto.com/u_15733329/5817690)